# How to split single rows of a CSV file into multiple depending on delimiter in 2nd column

Tags: csv, cut, split

My base.csv file has several entries a sample of which is below.

```
NAME,IP_ADDRESS,PRI_IP,APP_CODE,APP_NAME,OWNER
test2,10.9.7.12/10.222.101.11,10.9.9.12,545,myapp1,owner1
mytest,10.9.7.12,10.9.9.12,545,myapp1,owner9
checkthis,10.9.7.12/10.222.101.11/10.3.2.111,10.9.9.12,545,myapp1,owner7
```

Note: the second column is always a single or multiple IP address seperated by delimiter `/`

I wish to create `newbase.csv` with second colum always having only a single ip.

Thus the desired newbase.csv would be like

```
test2,10.9.7.12,10.9.9.12,545,myapp1,owner1
test2,10.222.101.11,10.9.9.12,545,myapp1,owner1
mytest,10.9.7.12,10.9.9.12,545,myapp1,owner9
checkthis,10.9.7.12,10.9.9.12,545,myapp1,owner7
checkthis,10.222.101.11,10.9.9.12,545,myapp1,owner7
checkthis,10.3.2.111,10.9.9.12,545,myapp1,owner7
```

Below give me the desired columns that i need but does not split rowns containing multiple ips in the second column into multiple rows.

```
cat -- base.csv | cut -d, -f2-5 > newbase.csv
```

Can you please suggest ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Miller nest](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-verbs.html#nest) function to *explode* values across records:

```
$ mlr --csv nest --explode --values --across-records --nested-fs '/' -f IP_ADDRESS base.csv
NAME,IP_ADDRESS,PRI_IP,APP_CODE,APP_NAME,OWNER
test2,10.9.7.12,10.9.9.12,545,myapp1,owner1
test2,10.222.101.11,10.9.9.12,545,myapp1,owner1
mytest,10.9.7.12,10.9.9.12,545,myapp1,owner9
checkthis,10.9.7.12,10.9.9.12,545,myapp1,owner7
checkthis,10.222.101.11,10.9.9.12,545,myapp1,owner7
checkthis,10.3.2.111,10.9.9.12,545,myapp1,owner7
```

With more recent versions, `--explode --values --across-records --nested-fs '/'` may be abbreviated to `--evar '/'` so

```
mlr --csv nest --evar '/' -f IP_ADDRESS base.csv >newbase.csv
```

Alternatively, with awk:

```
awk -F, '
  BEGIN{OFS=FS}
  {
    n = split($2,a,"/")
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
      $2=a[i]; print
    }
  }
' base.csv >newbase.csv
```

Comment: `mlr command not found` on my redhat Linux 7.1 host Is the `mlr` rpm present along with the dependencies for download ? Kindly share @steeldriver.

Comment: @Ashar I am not familiar with the RedHat packaging system - you will need to figure that part out yourself

Comment: amazing answer & thanks @steeldriver